# WPF threading and custom Powershell host - Command execution stopped because the user interrupted the command

Tags: wpf, powershell, powershell-sdk

I have a WPF app with a powershell custom host that runs a script that is stored in an embedded resource.  After loading, the user click the execute button and the script is Invoked but I see the following error:

**Command execution stopped because the user interrupted the command**

The user (ie, me) did nothing to interupt the script so I'm guessing that this is some sort of threading issue.

The application also accepts a command line parameter that tells the script to execute immediately.  When I first added this feature, the script ran perfectly, but I didnt see the WPF ui until this was completed so I added the following to the startup of the main window view model:

```
        var bgWork = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWork.DoWork += (s,e) => { };
        bgWork.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,a) =>
        {
            var app = (Application.Current as App);

            if (app.ExecuteImmediate && StartCommand.CanExecute(null))
                StartCommand.Execute(null);

        };
        bgWork.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The BackgroundWorker runs the Completed code on the UI thread.  This is just a little trick I use quite often and it works ok mostly.

So, a long question I know, but has anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

As a side or related issue, I also have problems updating the ui via data binding when a processes is running.  Eg, I have a status indicator in the status bar that switches between IDLE and BUSY but this never seems to change until it's too late.  The binding is working fine but it's like I need the old VB DoEvents() to be called.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved this after a coffee and a few minutes debugging.

There erorr was because I hadn't implemented the PromptForChoice method fully.

However, I still have problems with updating bindings.